# How to print a string before using "*" to unpack list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, unpack

Is it possible to print a string before using the `*` operator when unpacking a tuple:

```
m = ['b', 'a', 'e']
print(*m, sep = ',')

b, a, e
```

I tried to print something before it:

```
print("String: " + *m, sep = ",")
```

My desired output would be:

```
String: b, a, e
```

Is it possible to have a string print before this, and what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Yes, why don't you try?

Comment: `print('string', *m, sep=',')`…!?

Comment: deceze, is it possible to print that without the comma being after the string, and only having the comma apply to the items in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*m` unpacks the list `m` into separate arguments. It's equivalent to:

```
print('b', 'a', 'e')
```

You can add additional arguments before and after that:

```
print('string', *m, sep=',')
```

> is it possible to print that without the comma being after the string, and only having the comma apply to the items in the list?

Take your pick:

```
print(f'String: {", ".join(m)}')

print('String:', ', '.join(m), sep=' ')

print('String:', end=' ')
print(*m, sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
print(",".join(m))
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use

```
print(",".join(m))
```